# Как удалить переводы строк в textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется элемент textarea:

```html
<textarea
  /* отслеживает "Enter + Shift" */
  onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) {
    return event.shiftKey == 1;
  }">
text
</textarea>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как в textarea при вставке текста удалять символы новой строки для того что бы весь текст преобразовывался в 1 строку. То есть, если я сейчас скопирую какой-то текст содержащий переводы строк, то в textarea они так и вставятся - есть ли способ удалять символы новой строки автоматически?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429757/remove-line-break-from-textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь, решение на jq подойдет :)

```js
$('.js-textarea').on('input keypress paste', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.shiftKey == 1) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    let oldVal = $(this).val();

    $(this).val(oldVal.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,''));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="js-textarea" style="height: 200px; width: 300px"></textarea>
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо. Вы просто супер. Невероятная помощь.

Comment: Верный ответ, но непонятно зачем здесь jQuery если точно такой же код пишется без него